# How only grant read access to data that own specific value in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Here is a data structure in Firebase :

```
{
  "wall" : {
    "-cxwcxwcxw" : {
        "name" : "hello",
        "status" : 0
    },
    "-cxwfdscxw" : {
        "name" : "stack",
        "status" : 0
    },
    "-cxfdsqcxw" : {
        "name" : "overflow",
        "status" : 1
    }
  }
}
```

I want to only allow reading wall's item where status is 0, in the list scope. I mean get the list of wall's item that where status is 0;

So my rules are :

```
{
  "wall": {
    "$wall_item_id": {
       ".read": "data.child('status').val() === 0"
    }
  }
}
```

What is going wrong ?

EDIT :

I have checked with the Simulator, and I cannot get access to the list, but I can access to the items itself (where status == 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rules are correct, but only for individual items.

This read is allowed: `https://<my-firebase-app>/wall/-cxwcxwcxw`
This read is denied: `https://<my-firebase-app>/wall/-cxfdsqcxw`

[image]

But the Firebase Database does not filter out the inaccessible items. If one item in the list can't be read by the user, the entire list can't be read.

A way around this is to move the inaccessible items (`status === 1`) to it's own location.

```
{
  "validWall": {
    "-cxwcxwcxw" : {
        "name" : "hello",
        "status" : 0
    },
    "-cxwfdscxw" : {
        "name" : "stack",
        "status" : 0
    },
   },
   "invalidWall": {
    "-cxfdsqcxw" : {
        "name" : "overflow",
        "status" : 1
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes your are right, the item can be accessed but not the list of item. I think this will be difficult

Comment: Ah I see. Yes, the Firebase Database does not filter out the inaccessible items. If one item in the list can't be read by the user, the entire list can't be read.

Comment: Let me know if my answer works. It's good to keep the unanswered queue clear.

Comment: OK thank, please put the fact that this is not possible to list part of item with security rules, this is the answer here. And I will accept it.

Comment: No problem! Just did and also gave an suggestion of how you might be able to get around this.