# firebase ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid" not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, security, firebase

I started today with Firebase and try to create a sample iOS app.
At the moment I'm stuck with securing my data.

Lets say I have this demo data.

```
{
 "Demodata" : {
   "demodata-1" : {
      "id" : 1,
      "uid" : 1234
   }
 } 
}
```

and this rule file

```
 {
  "rules": {
    "Demodata" : {
      "$uid" : {
        ".read" : "auth.uid == $uid" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and a logged in user with the uid : 1234

I log in with this code.

```
 ref.authUser(email, password: password,
        withCompletionBlock: { error, authData in 
           completion(result: error)
 })
```

Then I try to get the data with this code.

```
  demoDataRef.queryOrderedByChild("id").queryEqualToValue(queryValue).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        // do some stuff once
        print(snapshot)
    })
```

But I never get the data back from Firebase. When I remove the rule and add a ".read" : true to the parent everything works.

I'm sure I miss something but at the moment I'm a little bit lost. Maybe some one can point me in to the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things wrong here. One of them is easy to fix, the other one is more difficult.

### 1. "Ordering skips a level"

You're missing a level in your JSON data. When you call `queryOrderByChild("id")` the ordering is applied to the "id" child property of *each child node* of `demoDataRef`.

To fix it, add a level for the users to your JSON:

```
{
 "Demodata" : {
   "demodata-1" : {
     "user1": { 
       "id" : 1,
       "uid" : 1234
     },
     "user2": {
       "id" : 2,
       "uid" : 2345
     }
   }
 } 
}
```

### 2. Rules are not filters

The second problem is that you're trying to execute a query on `Demodata`, but your user doesn't have read access to `Demodata`. This means that Firebase will immediately reject the operation. If you attach `withCancelBlock`, you'll see that rejection.

So while a user may be able to read a specific record (or even each specific record), they are not able to query the list of records. This is a common misunderstanding of Firebase's security rules that is covered in the documentation under [rules cascade](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-cascade) and [rules are not filters](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-filter).

Unfortunately this means that you'll typically have to pick a different way to structure your data. When storing users, the common solution is to store each user under their uid:

```
{
 "Demodata" : {
   "demodata-1" : {
     "1234": { 
       "id" : 1,
       "name" : "user1"
     },
     "2345": {
       "id" : 2,
       "name" : "user2"
     }
   }
 } 
}
```

Now each user can access their own profile with a direct lookup:

```
demoDataRef.childByAppendingPath(queryValue).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value...
```

Also see:

- [How only grant read access to data that own specific value in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025855/how-only-grant-read-access-to-data-that-own-specific-value-in-firebase/34027055#34027055)
- [Firebase rules - Cannot access to each node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249956/firebase-rules-cannot-access-to-each-node/31250735#31250735)
- [Show only items that have userid as child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172226/show-only-items-that-have-userid-as-child/29172555#29172555)

Comment: Thank you this explains a lot!